# Converting tuple to integer

Tags: python, string, dictionary, tuples, average

I have this python function that takes 2 arguments (*string , dictionary*) and returns a float. The function is designed to take the average of the integers within a dicionary of scores and strings.

```
def happiness_score(string, dic):
   keys = string.lower().split()
   v = sum(dic[key] for key in keys)
   return float(v)/len(keys)
```

I have this test case which works:

```
print happiness_score("a b" , {"a":(1.2) , "b":(3.4)})
>>> 2.3
```

I also have a test case with tuples:

```
print happiness_score("a b" , {"a":(1,2) , "b":(3,4)})
```

How can I change my code so that I can convert any given tuple to integer so that I can still run my program?

Comment: What do you mean by convert a tuple to an integer?  Do you mean sum the components of the tuple?  Do you actually mean convert a tuple to a float (should (1,2) become 1.2)?

Comment: Exactly how would you like to convert a tuple (a collection of values) to an integer (strictly one value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to use my ninja mind reading skills to guess how you want to convert a tuple to a float, Perhaps you want:

```
def tup2float(tup):
    return float('.'.join(str(x) for x in tup))
```

This will only work with 2-tuples...

Some results:

```
>>> tup2float((1,2))
1.2
>>> tup2float((2,3))
2.3
>>> tup2float((2,30))
2.3
>>> tup2float((2,32))
2.32
```

Comment: But what if you have zeroes? `tup2float((1, 064))` doesn't produce anything resembling `1.064` :)

Comment: @nneonneo -- You're right about that.  But I would say that's a design flaw in OP's code (if this is really what OP wants).  You can't write a converter which can deal with the case you mention because the information simply isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you want the answer in this case to be (2, 3). In other words, you want to treat each element in the tuple as the source of a separate mean.

```
def happiness_score(dic):
   scores = map(sum, zip(*d.values()))
   return [float(v)/len(dic) for v in scores]
```

The first step is to create a set of values for each tuple element:

```
d = {'a': (1, 2), 'b': (3, 4)}
zip(*d.values())
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Then apply sum to each tuple using map.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you read the file into a list called `lines`

```
hrs, miles = zip(*[(float(line.split()[-4]), float(line.split()[-2])) for line in lines if 'miles' and 'hrs' in line])
total_hrs = sum(hrs)
total_miles = sum(miles)
```